# While joining two dataframe in spark, getting empty result

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, datastax

I am trying to `join` two `dataframes` in spark from database Cassandra.

```scala
val table1=cc.sql("select * from test123").as("table1")

val table2=cc.sql("select * from test1234").as("table2")

table1.join(table2, table1("table1.id") === table2("table2.id1"), "inner")
  .select("table1.name", "table2.name1")
```

The result I am getting is `empty`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try pure sql way, if you are un-sure of the syntax of join here.

```
table1.registerTempTable("tbl1")
table2.registerTempTable("tbl2")

val table3 = sqlContext.sql("Select tbl1.name, tbl2.name FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 on tbl1.id=tbl2.id")
```

Also, you should see, if table1 and table2, really have same id's to do join on, in first place.

Update :-

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
```

Ideally, yes, csc should also work.
You should refer to http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html

Comment: `<console>:34: error: not found: value sqlContext
         val table3 = sqlContext.sql("Select tbl1.name, tbl2.name FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 on tbl1.id=tbl2.id")`   I have created the data frame table1 and table2 using cassandra context (cc).Will it work with sqlContext?

Comment: Updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

First union both data frame and after that register as temp table